# Haversine formula in DOCTRINE 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I need to transfer the query in PDO below to DOCTRINE:

```
$query = $con->query('SELECT *,
            ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('.$latitude.') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$longitude.') ) + sin( radians('.$latitude.') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, city_name
            FROM event INNER JOIN city ON event_city_id = city_id
            WHERE event_sin_active = 1
            ORDER BY distance');
```

So far I've been able to rewrite the doctrine part of this query. The problem appears when inserting in the SELECT the Haversine formula according to the questions: [SQL search using Haversine in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973878/sql-search-using-haversine-in-doctrine) e [How to calculate distance using latitude and longtitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084886/how-to-calculate-distance-using-latitude-and-longtitude)

The two tables in the database used are Event and City

```
    CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `event_image` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_tax_service` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event_sin_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



 CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When you try to run the query below, the system returns a blank screen and does not tell you which exception.
**What is the correct way to write this query?**

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->select("e, e.eventCityId,c.cityName, (6371 * ACOS(SIN(RADIANS($latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS(e.latitude)) + COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(e.latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(e.longitude) - RADIANS($longitude)))) as distance")
                ->from('\App\Entity\Event', 'e')
                ->innerJoin('\App\Entity\City', 'c', Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('e.eventCityId', 'c.cityId'))
                ->where('e.eventSinActive = 1')
                ->orderBy('distance', 'ASC');
```

I'm running this code inside a route in slimFramework. PHP and Mysql logs do not indicate error